# Symmetrical Graph (Integration)

Tags: integration, area

This is the question --> [image]

---

What I have done

Area = 2(0.9) + 2(-0.1) + 2(-0.3)

Area = 1.0 units

is this correct? I've never done questions like these so I'm not confident..

Comment: The answer $1$ is correct for the integral. I would not really call it area. True,  sometimes one calls areas below the $x$ axis negative, but that is not a universal convention.

Comment: Sometimes it's called a signed area or net area instead of the are.